# How can I put an image into a Shape without losing its aspect ratio?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to pick and image from computer and fit it into a Circle (JavaFX) but it keeps changing the aspect ratio to 1:1 and I don't know what to do, maybe there's another way for doing it but I don't know that much of JavaFX and I didn't find anything else over here.

Having [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlH3T.jpg) image, with an aspect ratio of 4:3, it changes the aspect ratio to 1:1 [(this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlySe.png).

Here it's the code of the "onClick" method:

```
@FXML
public void handleUploadImage(MouseEvent event) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    //Extensiones soportadas de imagen
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterjpg
            = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("jpg files (*.jpg)", "*.jpg");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterpng
            = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterjpeg
            = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("jpeg files (*.jpeg)", "*.jpeg");

    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterjpg, extFilterpng, extFilterjpeg);
    //Menu de seleccion de imagen
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    Image image  = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
    circleImage.setFill(new ImagePattern(image, circleImage.getCenterX()-circleImage.getRadius(), circleImage.getCenterY()-circleImage.getRadius(), 2*circleImage.getRadius(), 2*circleImage.getRadius(), false)); //circleImage.setFill(new ImagePattern(image)); -> do the exact same thing
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 solutions, maybe not as easy as you should expect.

#### 1- Create a square, centered image first

```java
Image square(Image img) {
    if (img.getHeight() == img.getWidth()) {
        return img;
    }
    // Smallest length
    int size = (int) (img.getWidth() > img.getHeight() ? img.getHeight() : img.getWidth());
    // left shift
    int x = ((int) img.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    // top shift
    int y = ((int) img.getHeight() - size) / 2;
    return new WritableImage(img.getPixelReader(), x, y, size, size);
}
```

and paint it as it is.

#### 2- Paint the image a bit outside of the circle

```java
ImagePattern pattern(Image img, double radius) {
    double hRad = radius;   // horizontal "radius"
    double vRad = radius;   // vertical "radius"
    if (img.getWidth() != img.getHeight()) {
        double ratio = img.getWidth() / img.getHeight();
        if (ratio > 1) {
            // Width is longer, left anchor is outside
            hRad = radius * ratio;
        } else {
            // Height is longer, top anchor is outside
            vRad = radius / ratio;
        }
    }
    return new ImagePattern(img, -hRad, -vRad, 2 * hRad, 2 * vRad, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried the second option and it works, you're my hero!